# Is it possible to create trading graph in react native (like in photo)?

Tags: react-native, graph, highcharts, linegraph, tradingview-api

Need help to create graph like in photo. Please suggest any third party library to build this king of graph.[image]

Comment: do you have any update if you found solution

Answer (score 1):

I think that this kind of chart could be created via using the Highcharts React Native wrapper - API: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native

It looks like a basic line chart with customized plotLine - API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines.label

Comment: Sebastian Wędzel: I have tried creating the graph but in that i am not able to set scrollbar. can you please hemp me out?

Comment: @ChetanPatil do you mean the scrollable plot area? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.scrollablePlotArea The scrollbar is a Highstock feature - https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/scrollbar, but The React Native wrapper doesn't support the Highstock charts and features.

Comment: @ SebastianWędzel Yes, scrollable plot area.
Also want to ask some questions regarding chart, how to change dynamic plot line in react native? I have found through react but not able to found in react native wrapper. Is it supported in react native? Also I want to change y axis at right side but opposite is not working

Comment: `how to change dynamic plot line in react native` - the same config which works in the React environment should do the same in the React Native. `Also I want to change y axis at right side but opposite is not working` Simple `yAxis.opposite` as true should be enough in this case - are you able to share your config?

Comment: @ SebastianWędzel thanks now I am able to plot the graph properly. But facing one issue while updating data on buttons click. not able to remove the old series. can you help me out?

Comment: @ChetanPatil please open a new issue with the code example for it.

Comment: @ SebastianWędzel opend up new issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65235495/trying-to-update-high-chart-data)