# Trying to update high chart data

Tags: react-native, highcharts

I am trying to update the data series on the update button by providing new series.  As the result, new series will be a plotting along with the old series.

And After plotting the new series, the values on are X-axis is clear up. Here I Am attaching the code snippet please have look.

Initial State config:

```
 this.state = {
  chartOptions: {
    credits: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'spline',
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Chart',
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        shadow: false,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        },
      },
    },
    xAxis: {
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      type: 'datetime',
      lineColor: '#999',
      lineWidth: 1,

      title: {
        text: 'Time',
        style: {
          color: '#000',
        },
      },
    },
    yAxis: [
      {
          title: {
          text: 'Value',
        },

        gridLineWidth: 1,

        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: true,
        

        plotLines: [
          {
            color: '#55c2ea',
            width: 2,
            value: props.data[0][1], // Need to set this probably as a var.
            label: {
              text: props.data[0][1],
              textAlign: 'left',
              verticalAlign: 'middle',
              style: {
                color: '#55c2ea',
                fontSize: 16,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#55c2ea',
                borderColor: '#55c2ea',
              },
              x: 330,
            },
          },
        ],
        accessibility: {
          enabled: true,
        },
        opposite: true,
      },
    ],
    time: {
      useUTC: false
    },
    series: [
      {
        showInLegend: false,

        color: '#FF0000',
        data: props.data.slice(0, props.tradingInterval),

      },
    ],
  }
};
```

Update Function:

```
updateSeries = () => {

this.setState({ chartOptions: {
  series: [
    
    { 
      showInLegend: false,
      color: '#FF0000',
      data: this.props.data.slice(0, 15),}
  ]
} })
```

}

Graph Render code:

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <HighchartsReactNative
      styles={styles.chart}
      options={this.state.chartOptions}
    />
    <Button
      title="Refresh"
      onPress={this.updateSeries.bind(this)}/>
  </View>


);
```

}

After updating graph looks like
[image]

**Class Component Code:** https://gist.github.com/cupatil/da00b0ab0866e3a4f9306f0425e92582

Also tried this code using a functional component.

**Using Functional Component Code:** https://gist.github.com/cupatil/2fc1862f64f3a511158ced3c6b64d215

But the same thing happens series changed but not able to plot the graph property as per the image. Also, X-Axis data not calculated properly.

**Sample Series data that I am using:**

[ { x: 1607883000000, y: 1.6093 },{ x: 1607882940000, y: 1.6094 },{ x: 1607882880000, y: 1.6093 },{ x: 1607882820000, y: 1.6094 },{ x: 1607882760000, y: 1.6094 },{ x: 1607882700000, y: 1.6094 },{ x: 1607882640000, y: 1.6095 },{ x: 1607882580000, y: 1.6094 },{ x: 1607882520000, y: 1.6095 },{ x: 1607882460000, y: 1.6093 },{ x: 1607882400000, y: 1.6095 },{ x: 1607882340000, y: 1.6095 },{ x: 1607882280000, y: 1.6088 },{ x: 1607882220000, y: 1.6096 },{ x: 1607882160000, y: 1.6095 },{ x: 1607882100000, y: 1.6096 },{ x: 1607882040000, y: 1.6096 },{ x: 1607881980000, y: 1.6096 },{ x: 1607881920000, y: 1.6097 },{ x: 1607881860000, y: 1.6097 },{ x: 1607881800000, y: 1.6099 },{ x: 1607881740000, y: 1.6101 },{ x: 1607881680000, y: 1.61 },{ x: 1607881620000, y: 1.61 },{ x: 1607881560000, y: 1.6099 },{ x: 1607881500000, y: 1.6099 },{ x: 1607881440000, y: 1.6099 },{ x: 1607881380000, y: 1.6098 },{ x: 1607881320000, y: 1.6099 },{ x: 1607881260000, y: 1.6098 },{ x: 1607881200000, y: 1.6098 },{ x: 1607881140000, y: 1.6098 },{ x: 1607881080000, y: 1.6099 },{ x: 1607881020000, y: 1.6098 },{ x: 1607880960000, y: 1.6099 },{ x: 1607880900000, y: 1.6098 },{ x: 1607880840000, y: 1.6098 },{ x: 1607880780000, y: 1.6099 },{ x: 1607880720000, y: 1.6098 },{ x: 1607880660000, y: 1.6096 },{ x: 1607880600000, y: 1.6097 },{ x: 1607880540000, y: 1.61 },{ x: 1607880480000, y: 1.6099 },{ x: 1607880420000, y: 1.6101 },{ x: 1607880360000, y: 1.61 },{ x: 1607880300000, y: 1.6101 },{ x: 1607880240000, y: 1.61 },{ x: 1607880180000, y: 1.6101 },{ x: 1607880120000, y: 1.6101 },{ x: 1607880060000, y: 1.61 },{ x: 1607880000000, y: 1.6099 },{ x: 1607879940000, y: 1.6099 },{ x: 1607879880000, y: 1.6098 },{ x: 1607879820000, y: 1.61 },{ x: 1607879760000, y: 1.6097 },{ x: 1607879700000, y: 1.6098 },{ x: 1607879640000, y: 1.6096 },{ x: 1607879580000, y: 1.6096 },{ x: 1607879520000, y: 1.6097 },{ x: 1607879460000, y: 1.6096 },{ x: 1607879400000, y: 1.6095 } ]

Comment: Would you be able to provide me with the entire start configuration for this chart? It should help me to reproduce the issue. We need to know how the `this.state.chartOptions` looks like.

Comment: @daniel_s I have updated the question by adding a state. chart options. Please let me know where I need to make changes

Comment: @danial_s Please also when I will update the series based on the above code lines are not draw properly. Also while changing data x-axis time series are not loading correctly

Comment: @daniel_s Can you please help I have also done the same thing using functional component but not able to plot the graph line correctly when we update data series.

Comment: After some time of playing with your code, I can't reproduce the problem described above. I've tested it with Native Highcharts (without any 3rd party library, React wrapper, and Highcharts React Native as well). The result is always the same, I mean, the series is updated correctly, and xAxis labels are visible.
Are you sure, that you're running the latest package version? Have you been able to notice any errors in debugger console?
Here is the .gif file which shows what I exactly see: https://gfycat.com/pl/keenembarrasseddutchshepherddog

Comment: I also have the same problem where the state is updated, but not all series is are plotted and the lines just disappears. Although i think this behaviour might not be related to state update. I have a parent scroll view for pull to refresh which cause a similar problem even when state is not updated.

Comment: @daniel_s Step to reproduce: First, you load only the minimum data set from the array and then try to update maximum data elements to data series then you can able to replicate this issue 

Please check the video for the same: https://vimeo.com/490801699

Comment: For me, i was using index property in the series. I stopped using the property, and everything went back to normal. Although there wasn't any duplicate with index property in the series, the plotted lines were disappearing. Not sure what could have cause this.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I was doing it the other way around, and that's why I was not able to reproduce the described error. Well, so now I see the problem, but as I thought, it's caused by passing not sorted (x ascending order) data, what you can notice after opening the browsers console, and see the [Highcharts #15 error](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/15/).

In order to make it work correctly, you need to **always** make sure that you're passing the data, which is sorted in ascending order (point x values are increasing along with the array element index).

So, to sum up, sort the array:

```js
[

  // data here

].sort((a, b) => a.x - b.x)
```

then change the the way you prepare (slice) the initial data:

```js
data.slice(data.length - 1 - 15, data.length - 1)
```

and now it should work as expected.

Live examples:

- Without React: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/37cdryg9/
- With React: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-q3whu

Comment: The same problem occurs when we use a small set of data (load 3 elements only), I just check in live example(With React: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-q3whu)

by changing below line on line numuber 146:

data.slice(data.length - 1 - 3, data.length - 1)

Comment: For me, it also works fine. Initially the chart has only three points, but after update remaining points are all visible, so I'm a bit confused about what the problem is. Could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Yes, the graph line is plotting properly but time labels on the x-axis are not visible for 3 elements. Please see this image for reference Link: https://imgur.com/NtRtPOP

Comment: Well, we've already discussed the problem with axis labels and `useUTC` here:https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native/issues/118.
In sum, I suggested to report it directly on the Highcharts repository, so have you tried to report it there, so that the core team would be take a closer look on that?

Comment: Actually, I have reported on high chart support. Not on the repository. I will also log there and mentioned this question link for there refrence

Comment: Could you tell me which support channel have you chosen? After all, I recommend to report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: I have reported on gitub after your comment

LInk:https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14824

HighChart Support Link (Existing One):
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=45539 
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=45544

Comment: Thank you ! As I mentioned, please report the problem here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues
It would allow you to discuss it with core developers directly, what should make this problem resolved a bit faster.

Comment: Thanks, Reported on HighChart Repo: github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14824

Comment: Yeah, right, missed it somehow. So, someone should contact you very soon. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, on GitHub they suggested drop-in a fix but I do not understand how to set in react native wrapper. means how to set ."Time.prototype.set " function as well module exporting.js 
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/1b7woqam/